# Вытащить всё что находится между скобками php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Читал документацию, пытался на её материале написать регулярку. Что-то не особо продвинулся вперёд (верней не так как хотелось). Вообщем решил написать регулярку, которая будет вытягивать текст между скобками. Вот что получилось:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]/', '[text0[text01][text02[text023[text0234]]]][text1]', $m);
// выводится: Array ( [0] => text01 [1] => text0234 [2] => text1 )
```

Пытаюсь вытащить все значения, которые лежат между всеми скобками. И результат записать примерно такой:

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        'text0' =>
        Array(
            0 => 'text01'
        ),
        Array(
            'text02' =>
            Array(
                'text023' =>
                Array(
                    0 => 'text0234'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => Array(
        0 => 'text1'
    )
);
```

Т.е. каждый уровень скобок будет отвечать за новый уровень массива.

Comment: у вас получилось найти ответ?

Comment: Не получилось, я решил пока что изучить лучше регулярки. Потом может решу эту задачу.

Comment: у меня есть ответ, без массива многоуровневого как вам нужно только находит слова, и состовляет из них массив

Answer (score 1):

Для начала можно найти верхний уровень вложенности:

```
preg_match_all("/\[(((?>[^\[\]]+)|(?R))*)\]/", "[text0[text01][text02[text023[text0234]]]][text1]", $output_array);
//  $output_array[1]=array(
//0 =>  text0[text01][text02[text023[text0234]]]
//1 =>  text1
//)
```

`$output_array[1]` будет содержать выражения первого уровня вложенности.
Затем соорудите рекурсию или цикл чтобы сделать эту-же операцию для каждого совпадения

Чтобы достать данные, которые не входят в скобки, используйте ту-же регулярку в функции замены:

```
preg_replace("/\[(((?>[^\[\]]+)|(?R))*)\]/", "", "text0[text01][text02[text023[text0234]]]");
//outputs:  text0
```